# twitter api Twython Raspberry Pi error

Tags: raspbian, python

I got an error in the twitter api Twython on my Raspberry Pi?

ERROR:

```
from .api import Twython
from requests_oauthlib import 0Auth1, 0Auth2

ImportError: No module named requests_oauthlib
```

Comment: According to this post: https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/issues/12#issuecomment-270035518 you'll want to make sure you have the latest version of Twython installed. `sudo pip3 install twython --upgrade` If that doesn't work please post more details about your setup, for example, are you using Python 2 or 3. Also do you have the module `request_oauthlib` installed?

Comment: I just added the contents of the comment to an answer, since it was the solution please accept the answer :)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you please edit your question to allow for code formating and proper spelling? See [how-to-ask](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)  [quality standards](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error).

Comment: @Ghanima could you please help me out? how to ask at stackoverflow.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like there's a missing library. Make sure to install the latest version of Twython.

`sudo pip3 install twython --upgrade`

Further reading:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=162900&p=1054189
[https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/issues/12#issuecomment-270035​518](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/issues/12#issuecomment-270035%E2%80%8B518)